# Adding slash to endpoint in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Instead of handling the WooCommerce Lost Password procedure in my-account/whatever, I want to do it in my-account/whatever/whatever. The problem is that in Woocommerce > Settings > Advanced > Endpoints, slashes are converted to hyphens.

Anyone knows how to handle this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to look here: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/my-account-menu.html

Comment: Cool! That what I was looking for. Thanks, Kees.

Comment: Please then check my answer for being correct, helps me ;)

Comment: Link is broken! can you elaborate what was it?